# mongodump assertion 17369

Tags: mongodb

Folks,
  When running a mongodump command, I get the following error:

```
assertion: 17369 Backing up users and roles is only supported for clusters with auth schema versions 1 or 3, found: 5
```

Any suggestions on how to address?  MongoDB v2.8

Comment: Is this mongodump version 2.8rc4 (the latest release candidate as of time of writing)? What version of MongoDB were the users created with? Can you show the exact mongodump command that you ran?

Answer (score 8):

Your version of mongodump might be to old. Running a v2.6 client with a v2.8+ server (with the new auth scheme) will give this error.

In my case I was running MongoDB v3.0 on the server, trying to make a dump with MongoDB v2.6 client. After [upgrading mongodb-org-tools to v3.0](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu) on my laptop, the problem went away.

Comment: This also works for error 17370 "_Restoring users and roles is only supported for clusters with auth schema versions 1 or 3, found: 5_". I was running version 2.6 **mongorestore** against 3.0 server.